# Rails, create an has_many ralation entry with different column type via nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

My app has below models:

```
Advertisment (has_many :images)
Image (belongs_to :advertisment)
Image Fields: advertisment_id, image_type, image_url
```

There are two image types in app 1. square and 2. banner.

What I want to be able to create a nested form with two browse button for both type images, and create an advertisement with images of both type.

Expected result:

```
#<Advertisment id: 1, name: "Test", content: "Lorem ipsum", created_at: "2014-08-01 20:14:06", updated_at: "2014-08-01 20:14:06">
[#<Image id: 1, advertisment_id: 1, image_url: "/images/test1.png", image_type: "banner",  created_at: "2014-08-01 20:14:09", updated_at: "2014-08-01 20:14:09">, <Image id: 2,  advertisment_id: 1,  image_url: "/images/test2.png", image_type: "square" ,created_at: "2014-08-01 20:14:26", updated_at: "2014-08-01 20:14:26">]
```

I need some guidance ASAP. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Why do not You just create 2 fields for each image like

```
#<Image id: 1, advertisment_id: 1, banner_url: "/images/test1.png",  square_url: "/images/test2.png", created_at: "2014-08-01 20:14:09", updated_at: "2014-08-01 20:14:09">
```

It will give You possibility to do it much easier, Ad will have only one image, with access to both `banner` and `square`.

The other option (if the banner and square images are same, only differing with size) is using CarrierWave gem and do something like

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  ...

  process :resize_to_fit => [700, 400]  # for banner

  version :square do
    process resize_to_fill: [300, 300]  # for square
  end
end
```

Comment: So use [CarrierWave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) gem for it as I described before, so You could acces banner with `@ad.image.image_url` and square with `@ad.image.image_url.square`.

Again, I do not understand why You want to use only one image_url column in Your image model. In this situation doing it with `banner_url` and `square_url` option makes perfect sense (IMHO of course) :)